# How to style the Background and the text color of the TableMenuButton context menu of a FXTable in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, contextmenu

When we enable the TableMenuButton on a FXTable we will get a context menu that enable to show and hide columns.

Knowing that my table do have a specific styling I want to restyle this context menu background color and text color.

I don't know how!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add a CSS stylesheet which modifes TableView's ContextMenu. Depending on which table view you are using, delete 'tree' or w/o 'tree' lines:

```
.table-view .column-header .context-menu,
.tree-table-view .column-header .context-menu,
.table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button .context-menu,
.tree-table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button .context-menu {
    -fx-background-color: black;
}
```

If you want to change menu item's background color:

```
.table-view .column-header .context-menu .menu-item,
.tree-table-view .column-header .context-menu .menu-item,
.table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button .context-menu .menu-item,
.tree-table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button .context-menu .menu-item {
    -fx-background-color: green;
}
```

If you want to change menu item label's color:

```
.table-view .column-header .context-menu .menu-item > .label,
.tree-table-view .column-header .context-menu .menu-item > .label,
.table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button .context-menu .menu-item > .label,
.tree-table-view > .column-header-background > .show-hide-columns-button .context-menu .menu-item > .label {
    -fx-text-fill: yellow;
}
```

Comment: please from where did you get this solution ?

Comment: @mohammedhousseyntaleb There's a default CSS stylesheet for all JavaFX elements - modena.css (link: https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470 ), inside of which are many predefined rules. I just used Find function in my browser (or editor, if downloaded the file) using some 'table' and 'menu'-close keywords, for example 'table-view', 'context-menu', 'menu-item', etc. Then I pasted it into my test code and did some modifications to see what happens with particular elements until I found what has to be changed to fit your needs.